# Кто знает как можно обновлять скрипты на странице каждые 5 секунд

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

Есть сайт с графиками где нужно обновлять постоянно скриптом данные . Я этого ни разу не делал , не сталкивался . Кто может знает ?

Comment: Добавьте код, графики бывают разные, по разному и обновляться в них данные будут.

Comment: См. setInterval в JS

Comment: Библиотек для графиков навалом, информации про ajax навалом, ищите и выбираете понравившееся и вперёд)

Answer (score 1):

Задача получения данных по инициативе сервера решается с помощью одной из технологии:`Server Side Events` которую я бы не рекомендовал использовать. Второй является `WebSocket`. Более подробно о 'WebSocket` можно почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets).

Comment: А можно ли добавить, почему Вы бы не рекомендовали SSE? Со своей задачей они вроде справляются.

Comment: Согласен, со своей задачей справляется, но есть недостатки: 1. Нельзя установить более 6 одновременных подключей на 1 сайте. 2. Не работает в неактивной вкладке. Из преимуществ нативно реализованы события.

Comment: И по внутренним ощущениям SSE медленнее развивается.